# Unexpected Behaviour of Switch-Case in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, turbo-c++

I Came across a problem in a book, when i ran the code in MSDOSBox TurboC++ For Windows 7, it showed me unexpected behaviour :-

the code was as follows :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
   char s = 3;
   switch(s)
   {
       case 1 :
       printf("\nDiamond");
       break;
       case 2 :
       printf("\nSpades");
       break;
       default :
       printf("\nHeart");
       break;
   }
   printf("\nI thought something like this");
   getch();
}
```

now the problem was…

the statement in default case was never got printed. it only printed "I thought something like this"

I gathered that 
in switch-case
char is treated as its value in ASCII code

Well…
here, the value to char s has been given 3 not '3'
but again
at least default case should be printed even if the value is nothing like any of the cases

well… if this helps..

i have tried to put

```
case 3 :
```

instead of

```
default :
```

now the statement i.e printf("\nHeart"); got executed and printed "Heart" on the screen

Comment: First, why you still use TURBO C COMPILER ?

Comment: It works fine for me with the MS C compiler...

Comment: sorry guys . .  actually it was MSDOSBox TurboC++

Comment: GCC, MinGW GCC, MSVC, etc. The first 2 are definitely free and accessible.

Comment: Well, Totally Fantastic, MSDOSBox **PLUS** TurboC++ !!!!!!!

Comment: Guys . .  do you got any solution ?

Comment: In DOS (not sure if this applies to your compiler, but some for sure), you may want to try replacing `\n` with `\r\n`. In case the compiler remaps line feeds in some way, it may be outputting a line in the default, but immediately overwriting that line with the printf at the end.

Comment: Turbo C++ has a decent debugger, step through the code.

Comment: So remove the last printf of your program and see if "Heart" is printed.

Comment: If you want a small, modern, cross-platform, relevant development environment, I suggest you download Code::Blocks with MinGW (http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26 - get the 96MB download) If you want the industry-standard complete with an unbeatable debugger and a user-base of millions, download Visual Studio Express. The tools are free, why not use the best ones for the job?

Comment: I think this might be an **encoding problem**, and make sure it was encoded as ANSI.

Comment: Or... try `int s = 3;` !

Comment: Or... try `case 1 :;`, `case 2 :;`, and `default :;`

Comment: Does both of them listed above helps?

Comment: @KVD : it was a problem question from a book. how can i change a question ? ..ha ha ha :D

Comment: @DemonSocket Even in GCC, sometimes fails if there is no `semicolon` after `colon`. Might be `tokens bug`!

Comment: Wait a second, How about disassembling?

Comment: Pasted your exact code from the question into TurboC++ 3.0, it prints "Heart" without a problem.

Comment: I'm suspecting that the code you are using is somehow different to what you have posted. Otherwise, I suspect sorcery as the next most likely possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you cut/paste this code from your source, or retype it?  If you retyped it, go back and make sure you spelled `default` correctly in the original.

A common error that usually elicits no warning from the compiler is to type something like `defualt` instead of `default` for that last label.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix Nope, it will record it as a goto location.

Comment: @Joe : no that was the correct code i typed, well… when i put case 3 :, in the place of default : the statement got printed i.e "Heart"

Comment: @Caesar Hm, a break inside a switch but outside the possible flow of a case should still trigger a warning, although with that compiler I guess I have to remember the good old days of compilers that don't warn for code that may be wrong, just syntax problems :)

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix:  Why would it be a parse error?  It's a perfectly valid label you could `goto`.

Comment: @KVD:  If your DOSBox + TurboC environment doesn't bridge to the Windows clipboard...  (I have no idea if it does.)

Comment: guys . . "heart" is getting printed when i put this into case 3 : but not in default :

Comment: @DemonSocket:  I understand that.  Can you post a _screen shot_ of your source code in the IDE?

Comment: @DemonSocket Maybe you can upload the original cpp source file.